# Will bootstrap 4 break grid gutter column is defined to to32 (2x16)?

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

Instead of having two margins of 15, I would like to use multiples something proportional to 4, so my design system has all sizes and components are multiples of 4

Comment: No, it won't break. Did you try it? https://www.codeply.com/go/Q4tAtJHgSk

Comment: yes I've tried, but I'm wondering if it will break its components. I'm using bootstrap 4 for multiple projects and I'm still trying to understand why the original bootstrap gutter uses an uneven number (30px px or 2x 15px margins) instead of material design which gutters and spaces are proportional to 4 or 8 points

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code, and modify the Sass variables file to create your own custom version.

There is a specific variable for the gutter width ($grid-gutter-width)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#variables

This section of the documentation has more details on how to do this.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/